# How to connect mysql to objective c?

Tags: mysql, objective-c

I have a login.php login and signup.php combo. I want to display a form in my app that will store user data and show exclusive views after sign in like a classic login/sign up combo. How do I connect my mysql database to my app? Will i be using json here or plists or both?

Comment: I've looked around online and I am using stack because i want the best most secure reference possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a web service and connect to it this way. Here's a link to a great tutorial for exactly what you're describing

[How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)

Hope this helps.

Comment: One of the links  I found. thanks for the recommendation, i'll check it out again.