# How to run mysql commands from terminal?

Tags: mysql, terminal

Last night I asked; [How to connect mysql to objective c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970285/how-to-connect-mysql-to-objective-c/24970365#24970365) and i started following the tutorial posted as an answer; I was simply wondering how to login to mysql and run commands from the terminal. I tried

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and it said no command found...I know i can create tables in phpmyadmin but id like to use the command line as well. Should i just run the sql queries in phpmyadmin?

Comment: do you have mysql client installed on the machine u run this command at ?

Comment: That is the command to start mysql. You will know you are in mysql when the terminal has this in the area before you type 'mysql >'             then you can use commands like select, insert, create table, etc etc

Comment: Yes, i am running xampp on mac

Comment: Do i have to enter any data before i enter ; 'mysql -u root -p' i stopped the xampp servers just in case but am still getting a command not found...ill figure it out

Comment: you probably dont have your mysql client executable added to your system paths. mysql -u root -p is a command to launch the mysql client in a terminal. once you launch that client only than you can start executing your mysql statements inside the client.  right now your system tells you it can not find the mysql client executable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mamp install for mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010302/mamp-install-for-mac)

Comment: I don't think so because the servers show a green light indicated no conflict on the usage of ports 80 and 3306

Comment: The MySQL executable's path on MacOS is somewhere like `/usr/local/mysql/bin` I think.  You would need to add that to your `$PATH` for it to be found, or just call it directly: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p`